# How to disable/modify AutoFocus and AutoWhiteBalance on Android Camera using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, focus, android-camera, autofocus

I'm using Android + Opencv(new to opencv) and I'm currently working with real time object detection (the object stays really close to the android device Camera) , and I noticed that the Android camera's autoFocus keeps modifying my frames (kind of 'zoom in' and 'zoom out' effect) which make it harder for me to keep tracking the object.

I need to turn the "AUTO FOCUS" off because in my case the more blurred image input I have, the better, and I also need to turn the AutoWhiteBalance off as well, or maybe set to a different value.

I would like to know how to do it through my OpenCV  CameraBridgeViewBase so I could modify the camera's Focus/WhiteBalance settings.

I've trying to find a way to solve it, and I noticed that many people face the same problems.

Here, at Stack Overflow, would be a great place to find someone who have worked with that and found a good way to overcome these problems.

Comment: would like to see an answer to this

Answer (score 2):

create your own subclass of `javacameraview`
`public class MyJavaCameraView extends JavaCameraView {`
where you can have access to `mCamera`; 
add whatever camera access using method you are interested in 
for example

```
// Setup the camera
public void setFlashMode(boolean flashLightON) {
    Camera camera = mCamera;
    if (camera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
```

and use this new class as part of the main activity

```
    //force java camera
    mOpenCvCameraView = (MyJavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
```

Comment: I tried this but mCamera is always null. What did I miss?