# Problems with turning off the autofocus on Android phone

Tags: java, android, opencv, autofocus

Working on my Samsung S6 camera calibration as a first step for further app development.
One of the perquisites for correctly working app is that the autofocus is disabled.
I used something like this:

```
mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
Camera.Parameters mParam = mCamera.getParameters();
mParam.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
mCamera.setParameters(mParam);
```

Previously, I checked that the "infinity" focus mode is available on my device.
Still, when running the app, I can clearly see that the focus is changing depending on the distance of the object in frame. "Fixed" mode is not available.

Am I doing something wrong?
I just want to have focus that will not change while running app.

I'm using OpenCV3.1 with Android Studio.

Comment: Please, could you be more specific? Why are you using deprecated Camera API 1? where are you using your autofocus disabling, I mean do you use this command before open the camera or before? Do you have any logcat relevant message?

Comment: Camera API looked much easier for me to implement than the Camera2.
I can see that I made a mistake by putting the whole thing under:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

First, I open the camera and then I disable the autofocus.

Comment: @uelordi Found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018814/how-to-disable-modify-autofocus-and-autowhitebalance-on-android-camera-using-ope?rq=1). That is something I could use, just i'm not sure where could I call `setFlashMode` from (or in my case `setFocusMode`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olivier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018814/how-to-disable-modify-autofocus-and-autowhitebalance-on-android-camera-using-ope?rq=1) helped me alot.
Did it as it is described.
Had to edit layout a bit.
Put the `setInfinityFocusMode` under the `onCameraViewStarted`.

Thanks Olivier ! ;)